# Executable not found despite PATH variable correctly set

Tags: windows, path, windows-xp

Really weird behaviour on my system. I can execute xilperl.exe in the following way on my system:

```
C:\Xilinx\10.1\ise\bin\nt>xilperl.exe
```

In order to make things easier I do not wanna add the whole path to execute xilperl,
so I added the "nt" directory to the PATH variable. Here you can see the content of PATH:

```
echo %PATH%
C:\Xilinx\10.1\EDK\bin\nt;C:\Xilinx\10.1\EDK\lib\nt; C:\Xilinx\
10.1\ise\lib\nt; C:\Xilinx\10.1\ise\bin\nt
```

So you can see the appropriate directories should be set, however, when trying to execute
xilperl it is still not recognised:

```
C:\>xilperl
'xilperl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone an idea what could go wrong here, I can't see what I missed.

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the PATH variable.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you are allowed to have spaces before or after the semicolons in your `PATH`. Remove the spaces and try again.

Comment: Indeed, that's it. Thank you so much, removing the spaces did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are missing the ending backslash in your paths</strike> You could try using backslashes :

```
C:\Xilinx\10.1\EDK\bin\nt\;C:\Xilinx\10.1\EDK\lib\nt\;
C:\Xilinx\10.1\ise\lib\nt\;C:\Xilinx\10.1\ise\bin\nt\
```

Spaces could also be a source of problems.